# Выполнение оператора в строке

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить оператор в строке. Например, надо выполнить

```
ComboBox1.Text:= '';
ComboBox2.Text:= '';
ComboBox3.Text:= '';
ComboBox4.Text:= '';
ComboBox5.Text:= '';
ComboBox6.Text:= '';
ComboBox7.Text:= '';
ComboBox8.Text:= '';
```

Я пишу

```
for I:=1 to 8 do
    Функция('ComboBox'+IntToStr(I)+'.Text:= '''';');
```

Есть такая Функция?

Comment: Что, что, что сделать???

Comment: @leklerk Чтобы код форматировался, нужно пропускать строки между блоками кода.

Comment: @leklerk, не забывайте принимать ответы. [Как принять ответ?](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading10). У Вас нет ни одного голоса "за" и ни одного принятого ответа. Это может повлиять на желание помогать Вам в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого вам следует использовать массив компонентов формы **Components**:

```
for i:=0 to form1.ControlCount-1 do
if(form1.Components[i] is TComboBox) then 
(form1.Components[i] as TComboBox).Text:='';
```

Comment: Ай-яй-яй. ControlCount <> ComponentCount.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, точно! Спасибо, что поправили, а то я почему-то не обратил на это внимания. Спасибо!

Comment: @Asen, и все-равно в коде оставили "form1.ControlCount-1" =)

Answer (score 3):

*В добавок к ответу Asen'a*

ComponentCount != ControlCount

хочу добавить, что в таком случае следует разделять компоненты, чтобы лишние в такую обработку не попали. Вдруг у вас 10 комбобоксов, а текст надо поменять только у пяти? В таком случае можно, НАПРИМЕР, использовать свойство TAG, разделяя им компоненты на группы:

```
for i:=0 to form1.ComponentCount-1 do  
  if (form1.Components[i] is TComboBox) then   
     if (form1.Components[i] as TComboBox).TAG = 1 then    
       (form1.Components[i] as TComboBox).Text:='';
```

Или размещать компоненты на разных панелях, и потом смотреть родителя:

```
for i:=0 to form1.ComponentCount-1 do  
  if (form1.Components[i] is TComboBox) then   
     if (form1.Components[i] as TComboBox).PARENT = Panel1 then    
       (form1.Components[i] as TComboBox).Text:='';
```

Answer (score 2):

Или, если набор компонентов используется неоднократно из разных мест, можно поместить их в массив или список:

```
var combos: array[0..2] of TComboBox;
....

  combos[0] := ComboBox1;
  combos[1] := ComboBox2;
  combos[2] := ComboBox3;

...

  for i := 0 to 2 do
    combos[i].Text:= '';
```